# How to scale predictors which have skewed distribution

Tags: logistic, data-transformation, ranking, skewness

I have 3 predictor variables `A,B,C` for ranking the documents . All three variables have positive correlation with ranking which means higher the value of A or B or C, higher the ranking. I am using a simple linear combination like `Score=0.2*A+0.3*B+0.5*C`, So that Score is always between 0 and 1

All the variables are defined to take values between 0 and 1 . My problem is that all three have very different distribution as follows

`A follows a uniform distribution`

`B takes a binary value 0 or 1`

`C  has a skewed distribution concentrated between 0.01 and 0.3 and very few instances where it is greater than 0.5`

As a result the final score gets dominated by contribution from A and B even though the weight for C is maximum (0.5)

How can I transform the variable C so that it contributes in the final Score.

Comment: In your first paragraph, the term you are looking for is [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination). For the skewed distribution you could use [histogram equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) in principle. However this would just be ad hoc, so I could nit say if it is appropriate without knowing more.

Comment: @GeoMatt22- Thanks . Histogram equalization is what I want to achieve in principle. As you said, What other information can I provide which can help